# How to copy a formula horizontally within a table using Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

So I have data that looks like this

[image: tables in excel]

The top two tables are averaging together certain data from the third table.

I'm trying to write a macro to add an extra column to each table, and simultaneously copy over the formula from the previous column. The adding of a new column is going great, but the copying-over is causing me problems.

This is what I have so far:

```
 Sub What()

Dim m As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim TableName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer

For i = 1 to 12
TableName = "Table" & i

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(TableName)

        .ListColumns.Add

    n = .ListColumns.Count
    m = n - 1

             'this is filling in the first row, with the column number (needed for formulas in the real data)
        .DataBodyRange(1, n).Value = n
        .DataBodyRange(1, n).NumberFormat = "General"

    LastRow = .ListRows.Count

             'this is where I'm trying to copy the formula over to the right
        For x = 2 To LastRow
            .DataBodyRange(x, n) = .DataBodyRange(x, m).Formula
        Next x

    End With

  Next i 

End Sub
```

The problem with this is that it's copying the formula straight, so my new column F of Table A1 is still averaging together the values of column E from Table A3.

Before the code I have now, I tried AutoFill (like this:

```
Range("K4").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K4:L4"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

)

but I don't need it to refer to a range, I need it to refer to a table cell, a la [ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(3, 2)](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables). Naively I attempted to sub this in for the destination

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns.Add
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(1, 2).Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(1, 3), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

and was told

> Run-time error '1004':  AutoFill method of Range class failed

All the resources I've googled refer to filling a formula down a column, but due to the orientation of my data I need it to copy horizontally, not vertically, and I haven't found anything for that. Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks so much~

Comment: Shouldn't the `Destination` in the `AutoFill` include _both_ the starting cell and the destination cell?

Comment: @BigBen Oh, maybe. I’ve tried making the destination the whole second row (Destination:=ActiveSheet.ListObjects(“Table1”).ListRows(2).Range) and got the same error as before

Comment: @BigBen I don’t know how I’d write it to only refer to two table cells, which is why I just skipped straight to the whole row

Comment: Works for me by enclosing the two cells within a `Range` call - like `Range(.DataBodyRange(1, 2), .DataBodyRange(1, 3))`. You should be able to grab the entire `Range` of a `ListColumn`, excluding the first cell, and autofill to the right in one go, though, instead of looping through rows.

Comment: @BigBen I'm getting the same error with `With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
        
        .ListColumns.Add
        .ListRows(2).Range.Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(.DataBodyRange(1, 2), .DataBodyRange(1, 3)), Type:=xlFillDefault
        
        End With`
Would you be able to post what worked for you?
**Edit**
Also tried `.ListColumns.Add
        .DataBodyRange(1, 2).Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(.DataBodyRange(1, 2), .DataBodyRange(1, 3)), Type:=xlFillDefault` but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The `Destination` should include *both* the starting cell/range and the destination cell/range.
- The `AutoFill` can also be done in one go, instead of the current loop from the 2nd row to the last row.
- No need to use `Select` or `Selection`.

Something then like this demonstrates the concept - modify as needed:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoFillRight()
    Dim myTbl As ListObject: Set myTbl = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
    Dim sourceRng As Range, destRng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long

    With myTbl
        .ListColumns.Add

        lastRow = .ListRows.Count
        lastCol = .ListColumns.Count

        If lastRow > 1 Then
            Set sourceRng = Range(.DataBodyRange(2, lastCol - 1), .DataBodyRange(lastRow, lastCol - 1))
            Set destRng = Range(.DataBodyRange(2, lastCol - 1), .DataBodyRange(lastRow, lastCol))

            sourceRng.AutoFill Destination:=destRng, Type:=xlFillDefault
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! Glad to help.